# Regex for Parsing Tweets for Links

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I found a link in a tweet that my current regex won't parse and I can't seem to figure out how to get it working (probably due to my ineptness with regex).

Here's the current code:

```
preg_match_all('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@',$description, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

And the Tweet that won't parse:

> Amazon: 14-day lending coming to
>   Kindle "later this year".
>   http://usat.me?128426

It's the usat.me link that's screwing things up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?((/)?([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)
```

Try that. Should work. modified the / to be (/)? meaning the last slash is supposed to be there 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it here, it's working at least for me:

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/

You can try this RegEx:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Comment: Didn't know about that site, thanks. Unfortunately it's still returning http://usat.me instead of the full URL.

Comment: Thanks, but the test tool is kicking this back: "Unknown modifier '\'"

Comment: nice page infinity. it's nice if you want to check something the fast way. but you should realy try regex coach http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ it's just neat. provides you with a tree representation of your expression and a step by step execution which can be pretty interesting for testing strings. it also provides a replacement engine for testing replacement strings like used in modrewrite ;-)